# EF returns DBNull when including nav property in eager loading

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to eager-load a list of objects from my database and include related objects. The list is supposed to contain all users related to a course subject and it's read from a Usersubject table. Each of those objects has a navigation property pointing to a User object (and has a foreign key in the db pointing to a row in the Users table).

For some reason when I write the `Include` line, my code starts to return DBNull.

```
var userDtos = await _dbContext.Usersubjects.Where(d => d.SubjectId == bySubjectId)
                                            .Include(d => d.User)
                                            .ToListAsync();
```

The Usersubject class:

```
public partial class Usersubject
{
    [ForeignKey("Subject")]
    public string SubjectId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;

    public int UserDeclaredKnowledgeLevel { get; set; }
}
```

The User class:
public partial class User

```
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I have other methods where I eager-load related data from other tables and it works, but not here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does lazy loading work?  You could also try specifying [Key] on the User.Id property

Comment: Navigation properties should be nullable as only those you load will be populated.

Comment: Nothing wrong in what you have shown. May be something in a code not shown here - for instance fluent configuration (I see no PK in the `Usersubject`, so it must be defined somewhere), or string db column type/collation differences. Need a repro, or you could try these two entities in a clean new project and see if it reproduces.

Comment: @IvanStoev, do I really need the PK for a table which only cotains many-to-many relationships?

Comment: @Val If you mean separate Id - no, but at least composite PK containing the two FKs. When I wrote "it must be defined somewhere", I meant that such composite keys are not defined automatically, and you need to use some attribute or fluent API code to map them which I don't see.